# ES12: Nullish coalescing operators & objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2021

For example I have an object like this:

```js
const a = {
 b: "value"
 // and also what about: c: '', or c: 0, c: false ?
};
```

And I'd like to assign a **'c'**, key to my object, but only if it's not assigned before.

Usually we do something like this:

```js
if (!a.c) {
  a.c = 1; // or without { } for a bit shorty way.
}
```

But ES12 standards introduce a bit more new Nullish coalescing and logical operators, so can someone explain to me how does it help me with replacing the example above and what about `null` and `0` as a number behavior (empty string and `false` behavior is also a plus)?

> *The real question behind it, is about: can use of this new feature really could cover all the cases and replace the example above in real-production projects, or is it still better to stay in a more traditional way. (Of, course it's all about syntax sugar staff, but I'd like to know more about coverage)*

Comment: do you want to replace zero?

Comment: Don't you mean `if (!a.c)`?

Comment: Hello @NinaScholz, I remember you by answering my other questions. To be honest, I'd like zero and `null` cases to be covered also.

Comment: And what about `false` and empty string... etc

Comment: @C.Champagne, yea, you right it was my mistake

Comment: Some options are: `a.c ??= 1`, or `a.c ||= 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) assigns the value only if the value of the left hand side is either `undefined` or `null`.

```
a.c ??= 1;
```

If you like to replace any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `''`, `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, you could take the [logical OR assignment `||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment).

```
a.c ||= 1;
```